# Parsing indoorGML in Android studio does not show a specific tag points to me

Tags: android, parsing, xml-parsing

I made a class to parse indoorGML information. The indoorGML has 5 layers.
All the parts work.
In fifth layer, I need to call a tag called posList:

```
        <indoorCore:CellSpace gml:id='L5C1'>
        <indoorCore:Geometry2D>
        <gml:Polygon >
        <gml:exterior>
        <gml:LinearRing>
    <gml:posList>529.0 840.25 529.0 803.51 540.0 803.51</gml:posList>
    </gml:LinearRing>
        </gml:exterior>
        </gml:Polygon>
        </indoorCore:Geometry2D>
        <indoorCore:PartialboundedBy>
        <indoorCore:CellSpaceBoundary gml:id='L5B1'>
        <indoorCore:geometry2D>
        <gml:LineString>
    <gml:posList>540.0 803.51 529.0 803.51 529.0 840.25</gml:posList>
    </gml:LineString>
        </indoorCore:geometry2D>
        <indoorCore:duality>
        <indoorCore:Transition xlink:href='#L5T1'/>
        </indoorCore:duality>
        </indoorCore:CellSpaceBoundary>
```

I need the points inside tag posList which are inside the tag polygon. I wrote the parsing like this:

```
 while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

        switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                currentTagName = parser.getName();
                if (currentTagName.equals("gml:Polygon")) {
                    inPolygon = true;
                } else if (currentTagName.equals("indoorCore:SpaceLayer")) {
                    String layer = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                    currentLayer = layer;
                    if (layer.equals("L5")) {
                       startOfFifthLayer = true;
                    }
                } else if(currentTagName.equals("gml:name")) {
                    inName = true;
                    // inNodes=true;
                    // Log.d("name", "true");
                }

                    if(currentTagName.equals("gml:posList")) {

                        inLayerFivePolygon = true;

                        Log.d("Polygon5", "true");

                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (currentTagName.equals("indoorCore:SpaceLayer")) {
                    String layer = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                    currentLayer = layer;
                    currentTagName = parser.getName();
                    if(currentLayer.equals("L5")) {
                        endOfFifthLayer = true;
                    }
                }


                break;
            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                if (inName) {
                    // put posList points in an array
                    String points = parser.getText();
                            Log.d("PlaceName MapPlace", points);
                    String[] split = points.split(" ");
                    inName=false;

                } else if(inLayerFivePolygon){
                    String points = parser.getText();
                          Log.d("Area MapPlace", points);
                    String[] split = points.split(" ");
                    inLayerFivePolygon=false;
                }
                break;
        }
        if (endOfFifthLayer) {
            break;
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }
}
```

When I just parse tag posList, my program can read the points. But when I want to filter it and put it inside the polygon tag, it does not show the points to me in  the Log.

Do you know what is the trick?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing the condition of testing the layer in the  case XmlPullParser.START_TAG :

```
            else if (currentTagName.equals("indoorCore:SpaceLayer")) {
                    String layer = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
                    currentLayer = layer;
                    if (!layer.equals("L5")) {
                       inFifthLayer = false;
                    }else {
                        inFifthLayer = true;
                        startOfFifthLayer = true;
                    }
```

Then to control the tag, moreover testing the tag, I control the layer again, like this:

```
         if(currentTagName.equals("gml:posList") && inFifthLayer) {

                    inLayerFivePolygon = true;

                    Log.d("Polygon5", "true");

                }
```

Finally in the XmlPullParser.TEXT, I parse the points I need like this:

```
      XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                if(inLayerFivePolygon){
                    String points = parser.getText();

                    String[] split = points.split(" ");
                    //ArrayList<String> finalPoints = convertToPolygon(points);
                   // Log.d("Area MapPlace", finalPoints.toString());
                    Log.d("Area MapPlace2", points);

                  inLayerFivePolygon=false;

                }
```

Comment: May ask which maps do you use to display IndoorGML?